# Percentage Formatting issue [visualforce] due to locale US vs Germany

Tags: apex, visualforce, format, percent

I have a visualforce page and when i submit my commission percentage from a campaign plan in germany it turns 15.00% into 1.500,00%

It is currently set up on the visualforce page like:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Commission %">  
    <apex:inputField value="{!newENT.cme.Commission_Percentage__c}" style="width:60px;" id="inputCommission" onkeyup="changeCommission(this);"/>
</apex:column>
```

As well as further down the bottom which I assume is the process done when the save process takes place:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Commission %">  
    <apex:inputField value="{!mapExistWrapper[existENT].cme.Commission_Percentage__c}" style="width:60px;" id="inputCommission" onkeyup="changeCommission(this);" rendered="{!mapExistWrapper[existENT].isEdit}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!mapExistWrapper[existENT].cme.Commission_Percentage__c}" style="width:60px;" id="outputCommission" rendered="{!NOT(mapExistWrapper[existENT].isEdit)}"/>
</apex:column>
```

I am assuming I have to do some manual formatting on the outputfield but am not sure where to begin.

Comment: are you sure the controller, Javascript or some other formula field isn't multiplying by 100? This doesn't seem like it should be a locale issue

Comment: positive its a formatting issue in salesforce i think